# erlang convert complex binary structure to JSON

Tags: erlang

I have a binary <<"{\"resp_child\":\"0\"}\n">> (as you can see it includes JSON) and I would like to extract this 0 as binary <<0>> from this binary.

I am new to erlang, i was trying

```
string:join(binary_to_list(<<"{\"resp_child\":\"0\"}\n">>), "")
```

but i get the JSON string as a result.

```
"{\"resp_child\":\"0\"}\n"
```

Don't know what to do further to get <<0>>.

Thank you.

Comment: Try parsing the Json and extract the 0. Then you could just use a list_to_integer("0") to convert it.

Comment: It might make your example more clear if you replaced "0" with something like "110101" since 0 is 0 whether it's binary or not ;-)

Comment: 0 does not mean binary digit (0,1). It can be any digit between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to use one of the Erlang JSON parsing library?

1. [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx)
2. [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy)
3. [mochijson2](https://github.com/bjnortier/mochijson2)

   proplists:get_value(<<"resp_child">>, jsx:decode(<<"{\"resp_child\":\"0\"}\n">>)).

So if you need to replace <<"0">>, <<"1">>, ... <<"9">> to <<0>>, <<1>>, ... <<9>> you can write converting function for this

Comment: Thanks man, i used mochijson2 to get this work. Thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this code worked for me.

```
Struct = mochijson2:decode(<<"{\"resp_child\":\"0\"}\n">>),
{struct, JsonData} = Struct,
Digits = proplists:get_value(<<"resp_child">>, JsonData).
```

Digits is <<0>>, that what i want.

You can read more about proplists at: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html.

Thanks :)